# Bootstrap menu line breaks

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some trouble having a 'pull-right' element in a navbar remain on the same line as the menu. I've set it up in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g34Jf/).
Here's the general outline:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top hidden-print">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
       <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li>....</li>
       </ul>
       <div class="pull-right">
         <ul class="nav pull-right">
           <li>....</li>
          .... and so on
```

Ideally the menu items, and user dropdown would be on the same line. The menu bar should have its height determined by the button sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `pull-left` the list:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left">
```